# How to fix InvalidIndexError when its asking for uniquely vlaued Index objects?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conda

I'm using a package called [pyDESeq2](https://github.com/owkin/PyDESeq2).
Things went smoothly until I was near the final end to run a `deseq2` command. It gave me an error `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`
However, my index object should be unique.

The input file, `.csv`, looks like this, in actuality the dimension is 13 columns by 24500 rows.

| GeneID | Sample1 | Sample2 | Sample3 | Sample4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 77 | 51 | 98 | 0 |
| Beta | 0 | 0 | 71 | 4 |
| Cena | 823 | 856 | 0 | 0 |

This is my code:

```
from pydeseq2.dds import DeseqDataSet
from pydeseq2.ds import DeseqStats

import pandas as pd

counts = pd.read_csv('filename.csv').set_index('GeneID')
counts # displays the re-indexed data frame

counts = counts[counts.sum(axis = 1) > 0] # filter out columns with 0 
counts # dimension is now 19222 rows x 12 columns
counts = counts.T
counts

metadata = pd.DataFrame(zip(counts.index, ['Het','Het','Het','Het', 'Cre_WT', 'Cre_WT', 'Cre_WT', 'Cre_WT', 'WT_naked','WT_naked','WT_naked','WT_naked']),
                        columns = ['Sample', 'Condition'])

metadata = metadata.set_index('Sample')
metadata

dds = DeseqDataSet(counts=counts,
                  metadata = metadata,
                  design_factors ="Condition")

dds.deseq2()
```

My suspicion is that `DeseqDataSet` may be causing the error but when I look at the documentation, it should not be a big problem when I run `dds.deseq2()` later. The message when running `dds = DeseqDataSet()` is:

```
/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anndata/_core/anndata.py:1900: UserWarning: Variable names are not unique. To make them unique, call `.var_names_make_unique`.
  utils.warn_names_duplicates("var")
/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydeseq2/dds.py:257: UserWarning: Some factor levels in the design contain underscores ('_').
                    They will be converted to hyphens ('-').
  self.obsm["design_matrix"] = build_design_matrix(
```

I don't know where in my code it's flagging this problem and it's asking me to `.var_names_make_unique`

What I tried:
I looked at the csv file to see if I missed indexing but nothing wrong there
I looked at the documentation to see if I need to add a parameter but my code should be workable

Comment: Hi, what is the output of `pd.read_csv('filname.csv')["GeneID"].duplicated().sum()`?

Comment: `pd.read_csv('filename.csv')` reads the csv file and I provided what that file looks like (the table above). `GeneID` columns is just the name of the genes so you won't get anything summing them @Laurent

Comment: Read again, please, I'm not summing the names, but the number of potential duplicates. Cheers.

Comment: @Laurent sorry misunderstood.  There are 4

Comment: So the column you use as index contains duplicates, leading to `InvalidIndexError`. There are several ways to deal with this, but try first to drop duplicates just to confirm that this is the only issue: `counts = pd.read_csv('filename.csv').drop_duplicates(subset="GeneID").set_index("GeneID")`. Cheers.